# What is the defintion of "H preserves all small products and equalizers"?

Tags: category-theory, definition

> If $C$ is a complete category, and $H:C \rightarrow D$ preserves all small products and all equalizers (of parallel pairs) prove that $H$ is continuous.

I'm trying to prove this theorem but I'm not sure what "**preserves all small products and all equalizers**" means.

**Does it mean**:  $C$ has ALL products and ALL equalizers and if $\bar c$ is a product in $C$ and $f,g$ are parallel arrows in  $C$ with equalizer $e$ that $H\bar c$ is a product in $D$ and $Hf, Hg$ are parallel arrows with equalizer $He$?

**Or does it mean**:  for the products and equalizers THAT EXIST in $C$, ALL $H\bar c$ and $Hf, Hg$ and $He$ as previously defined are products and equalizers in $D$?

Comment: It means the latter.

Comment: However, as “$C$ is a complete category” it also means the former in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From user k.stm' comments:

> It means the latter.
>
> However, as "$C$ is a complete category" it also means the former in this case.